# Sql Query for grouping dates in groups of bracketing start and end

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in following table

```
+------------+----------+------------+
| Event name |Date      |Action      |
+------------+----------+------------+
| Event A    |10/08/2018| Started    | 
| Event B    |10/08/2018| Started    | 
| Event A    |11/08/2018| Ended      | 
| Event B    |12/08/2018| Ended      | 
| Event A    |13/08/2018| Started    | 
| Event A    |14/08/2018| Ended      | 
+------------+----------+------------+
```

I am trying to write a query where I want to list out all dates for which an events was ongoing.

```
    +------------+----------+------------+
    | Event name |Date      |Status      |
    +------------+----------+------------+
    | Event A    |10/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event A    |11/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event A    |12/08/2018| null       | 
    | Event A    |13/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event A    |14/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event A    |15/08/2018| null       | 
    | Event B    |10/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event B    |11/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event B    |12/08/2018| Ongoing    | 
    | Event B    |13/08/2018| null       | 
    | Event B    |14/08/2018| null       | 
    | Event B    |15/08/2018| null       | 
    +------------+----------+------------+
```

I was able find one continuous range by taking min of started and max of ended but need help with how to break it into ranges.

Comment: do you have a dates table?

Comment: I have a date range , anything greater than 01-08-2018 and less than equal to current date. @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: @ila Did your mysql version support window function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` in the date table then `LEFT JOIN` base on it.

If your mysql didn't support window function you can try to use select subquery make row number by `Eventname` and `Action` to let the result make start date to end date table.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    Eventname varchar(50),
    Date date,
    Action varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Event A' ,'2018/08/10','Started'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Event A' ,'2018/08/11','Ended'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Event B' ,'2018/08/10','Started'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Event B' ,'2018/08/12','Ended'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Event A' ,'2018/08/13','Started'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Event A' ,'2018/08/14','Ended'); 


create table cT(
  Date date
);


INSERT INTO cT VALUES ('2018/08/10'); 
INSERT INTO cT VALUES ('2018/08/11'); 
INSERT INTO cT VALUES ('2018/08/12'); 
INSERT INTO cT VALUES ('2018/08/13'); 
INSERT INTO cT VALUES ('2018/08/14'); 
INSERT INTO cT VALUES ('2018/08/15');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Eventname,
  ct.Date,
  CASE WHEN t2.Action IS NOT NULL THEN 'Oppening' ELSE NULL END dt
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Eventname FROM T ) t1 CROSS JOIN CT ct
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t1.Eventname,
         t1.date 'startdate', 
         t2.date 'enddate',
         t1.Action
  FROM (
     SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM T tt 
              where tt.date <= t1.date and tt.Eventname = t1.Eventname and tt.Action = t1.Action) rn 
    FROM T t1 
    where Action = 'Started'
  ) t1 INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM T tt 
              where tt.date <= t1.date and tt.Eventname = t1.Eventname and tt.Action = t1.Action) rn 
    FROM T t1 
    where Action = 'Ended'
  ) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn and t1.Eventname = t2.Eventname
) t2 on ct.Date BETWEEN t2.startdate AND t2.enddate and t1.Eventname = t2.Eventname
WHERE ct.Date between '2018/08/10' and '2018/08/15'
ORDER BY t1.Eventname,ct.Date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18579f/28/0)**:

```
| Eventname |       Date |       dt |
|-----------|------------|----------|
|   Event A | 2018-08-10 | Oppening |
|   Event A | 2018-08-11 | Oppening |
|   Event A | 2018-08-12 |   (null) |
|   Event A | 2018-08-13 | Oppening |
|   Event A | 2018-08-14 | Oppening |
|   Event A | 2018-08-15 |   (null) |
|   Event B | 2018-08-10 | Oppening |
|   Event B | 2018-08-11 | Oppening |
|   Event B | 2018-08-12 | Oppening |
|   Event B | 2018-08-13 |   (null) |
|   Event B | 2018-08-14 |   (null) |
|   Event B | 2018-08-15 |   (null) |
```

If support window function you can use `row_number` with it to make it.

```
SELECT 
  t1.Eventname,
  ct.Date,
  CASE WHEN t2.Action IS NOT NULL THEN 'Oppening' ELSE NULL END dt
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Eventname FROM T ) t1 CROSS JOIN  cT ct
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t1.Eventname,
         t1.date 'startdate', 
         t2.date 'enddate',
         t1.Action
  FROM (
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Eventname,Action ORDER BY date) rn 
    FROM T t1 
    where Action = 'Started'
  ) t1 INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Eventname,Action ORDER BY date) rn 
    FROM T t1 
    where Action = 'Ended'
  ) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn and t1.Eventname = t2.Eventname
) t2 on ct.Date BETWEEN t2.startdate AND t2.enddate and t1.Eventname = t2.Eventname
WHERE ct.Date between '2018/08/10' and '2018/08/15'
ORDER BY t1.Eventname,ct.Date
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqFfpwNtrbRs2txtLZUibE/0)

Comment: was expecting Event A | 2018-08-12 |   Ended to be Event A | 2018-08-12 |   null since event A was not ongoing on 12.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the followibg query:
Let's call your table events

The 1st thing we need to to is join it to itself, to get the starts on the same row as ends:

```
    SELECT * FROM events st 
INNER JOIN events end ON st.event = end.event AND end.status =  'ended' AND event.date < end. date
 WHERE st.status = 'started'
```

Next, we want to get the earliest end, for each start,for that we'll add another left join, filtering out what isn't, by date differnce and NULL
We'll get just the ongoing cases:

```
 SELECT st.event_name, st.date AS start_date, end.date AS end_date FROM events st 
INNER JOIN events end ON st.event_name = end.event_name AND end.status =  'ended' AND event.date < end.date
LEFT JOIN events er ON er.event = end.event_name AND er.status = 'ended'
AND er.date < end.date
 WHERE st.status = 'started'
AND er.event_name IS NULL
```

Finally we join the query we wrote to the original table and get your desired output :

```
    SELECT events.event_name, events.date, IF(ong.event_name IS NULL, 'not active', 'ongoing') AS status FROM events
LEFT JOIN (SELECT st.event_name, st.date AS start_date, end.date AS end_date FROM events st 
    INNER JOIN events end ON st.event_name = end.event_name AND end.status =  'ended' AND event.date < end.date
    LEFT JOIN events er ON er.event = end.event_name AND er.status = 'ended'
    AND er.date < end.date
     WHERE st.status = 'started'
    AND er.event_name IS NULL) ong ON
ong.event_name = events.event_name AND ong.start_date >= events.date AND events.date <= ong.end_date
```

Notice that this will work as long as the same events do not start and end on the same date
Its best if your table holds DATETIME for the exact occurrence

Comment: ...and as long as the data set is fairly small

Comment: @Strawberry not relavitely.

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions, that's a pain in the butt... But it might be possible with extensive subquerying.

First `CROSS JOIN` the events and the days to have your event day matrix.

To check, if an event is ongoing, check if there are any start actions for it, that are before or on the current in the matrix day. That can be done by using `EXISTS`.

Then check, if there a no ending actions before the day in the matrix and after the last starting action before or on the day in the matrix. To do so use `NOT EXISTS` and aggregation (`max()`), the latter to get the last starting action.

```
SELECT e1.eventname,
       d1.date,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM event e2
                             WHERE e2.eventname = e1.eventname
                                   AND e2.date <= d1.date
                                   AND e2.action = 'Started')
              AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM event e2
                                     WHERE e2.eventname = e1.eventname
                                           AND e2.date < d1.date
                                           AND e2.date >= (SELECT max(e3.date)
                                                                  FROM event e3
                                                                  WHERE e3.eventname = e1.eventname
                                                                        AND e3.date <= d1.date
                                                                        AND e3.action = 'Started')
                                           AND e2.action = 'Ended') THEN
           'Ongoing'
       END status
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT eventname
                             FROM event) e1
            CROSS JOIN date d1
       ORDER BY e1.eventname,
                d1.date;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f0b5c/1) (Note, I added some extra events just going on for one day and one, that hasn't ended yet (or in the given period), to demonstrate that these cases are covered too. It won't work from the other end though, that is if there is only an ending action, it won't show the respective event as ongoing from the beginning of the range to the day that the ending action occurred.)